# How to find the position of a Rect in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to make a code that moves a rect object (gotten with the get_rect function) but I need its coordinates to make it move 1 pixel away (if there are any other ways to do this, let me know.)

Here is the code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 1920, 1080
black = 0, 0, 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
rectball = ball.get_rect()
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
rectball.move()
screen.fill(black)
screen.blit(ball, rectball)
pygame.display.flip()
```

You will notice that on line 11 the parameters are unfilled. This is because I was going to make it coords + 1.

Comment: Please correct your indentation. I've put your code in code blocks (rather than just prose), but the indentation was already lost. It's very significant to Python semantics.

Answer (score -1):

If I am correct I think it is rect.left or rect.top that gives it. Another method is to create another rectangle and check if the rectangle is in that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).